# Why can't a semicolon be inserted through JavaScript in a 'style' attribute?

Tags: javascript, html

I was trying to change the background colour of `body` with JavaScript and observed that the following doesn't work:

```
document.body.style.background = "#000;"
```

But if I omit the semicolon then it works:

```
document.body.style.background = "#000"
```

Why is it so? Isn't `#000;` still a string?

Comment: It is still a string but it's invalid.

Comment: is `#000;` a valid value for `background`? can you put into css like this `background-color: #000;;`

Comment: So does javascript automatically put `;` after `background: #000`?

Comment: you are adding a syntax error by doing so...because its not a valid color value...nd yes javascript automatically does it for us...

Comment: No, JS doesn't insert the semicolon because it's not part of the value.

Answer (score 6):

`;` isn't part of the value. It's a style *separator*.

```
selector {
    styleName: styleValue;
    /* Separator --------^----- */
}
```

From [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#rule-sets):

> A rule set (also called "rule") consists of a selector followed by a declaration block.
>
> A declaration block starts with a left curly brace (`{`) and ends with the matching right curly brace (`}`). In between there must be a list of zero or more **semicolon-separated** (`;`) declarations.

Your second example (without the `;`) is correct. Your first example fails to set the style because the value `#000;` is invalid, so the browser ignores it.

Comment: I thought if I have to add multiple styles then I have to manually insert `;`. E.g. After `document.body.style.background = "#000"` if I do `document.body.style.width = "100px" ` then the output would be `<body style="background: #000 width: 100px"></body>` -- no semicolon after `#000`. But seems like javascript automatically insert semicolon when multiple styles are added.

Comment: @user31782: You're confusing CSS blocks with style values. The `style` property on elements is an object, with properties for the individual values. No separators required, they're discrete properties. "JavaScript" isn't inserting semicolons. It's setting properties. The browser will render the serialized result correctly with embedded semicolons if you get the `style` *attribute* from the element, yes.

Answer (score -2):

Because when you set background style to `#000`, it outputs `background: #000`. This is not a proper CSS rule.